# How to replace part of the textContent in DOM element by inserting an html tag <span>

Tags: javascript, dom, replace

I'm trying to make a function to change the background of the strings I'm looking for.
If I do it via textContent, the tags are printed on the page.
If I do it via innerHTML - it also captures the content of the href attribute.

```
    const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item span');
    const searchedText = 'apple';
    const regEx = new RegExp(searchedText, "ig");        

    for (const item of items) {
        item.innerHTML = item.innerHTML.replace(regEx, `<span class="red">${searchedText}</span>`);
    }
```

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: Where's the href attribute?

Comment: Please edit your question and include the relevant HTML. Also, what ***specifically*** is the issue. Are you getting an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to change the background of specific strings within the content of HTML elements with the class "item" and "span." You want to highlight occurrences of the `searchedText` with a red background. However, there are a couple of issues in your code that need to be addressed.

1. You're using the `searchedText` variable before it is defined. You need to declare and initialize `searchedText` before creating the regular expression.
2. Using `innerHTML` to manipulate content can be tricky and can lead to unexpected results, especially when dealing with HTML tags within the content.

Here's a modified version of your code that addresses these issues:

```js
const searchedText = 'apple';
const regEx = new RegExp(searchedText, "ig");
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item span');

items.forEach(item => {
    const textContent = item.textContent;
    let newTextContent = textContent.replace(regEx, match => `<span class="red">${match}</span>`);
    item.innerHTML = newTextContent;
});
```

In this code, we first define the `searchedText`, create the regular expression, and then iterate through the selected elements to replace the occurrences of `searchedText` with a `<span>` element that has a class "red" for styling. This approach ensures that only the text content is replaced, and it won't interfere with HTML tags or attributes.

Comment: Yes thank you. I put this (searchedText before it is defined) just for demonstration. I changed it.